# Compilation error - duplicating class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compilation

I am trying to `Make project` in IDEA and i have compilation error. How to solve this?
I dont have duplicated classes in project. When I am pressing `Jump to source` it shows me the class from directory `target` of project.

```
duplicate class: com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemStreet_
```

and the same with all classes in project

IDEA 11.1.3
UBUNTU 12.04
JBoss as 7

additional code:

```
Round 1:
    input files: {com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBaseShortening_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreetShortening_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemAltNames_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchem_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.RQObject_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrBuilding_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSettings_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrCity_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemStreet_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBuilding_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreet_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.KladrUpdateDAO, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.KladrStreetDAO, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.RQObject, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSettings, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrBuilding, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBaseShortening, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrCity, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemStreet, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemAltNames, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchem, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.KladrStreetShorteningDAO, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.BasicKladrDAO, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.KladrBuildingDAO, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.dao.helper.LazyModelProperties, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreet, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBuilding, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreetShortening}

    annotations: [javax.annotation.Generated, javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel, javax.ejb.Stateless, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute, org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout, javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass, javax.persistence.Id, javax.persistence.Column, javax.persistence.Version, java.lang.Override, javax.persistence.Entity, javax.persistence.Table, javax.persistence.GeneratedValue, javax.persistence.Inheritance, javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty, javax.validation.constraints.Digits, java.lang.SuppressWarnings]

    last round: false

Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 1.2.0.Final

Processor org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor matches [javax.persistence.Entity, javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass] and returns false.

Processor org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor matches [javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute, javax.persistence.Column, javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, javax.persistence.Table, org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout, java.lang.Override, javax.persistence.Id, javax.persistence.Version, javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass, org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty, javax.ejb.Stateless, javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel, javax.persistence.Entity, javax.validation.constraints.Digits, javax.annotation.Generated, java.lang.SuppressWarnings, javax.persistence.Inheritance, javax.persistence.GeneratedValue] and returns false.

Round 2:

    input files: {com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemStreet_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBuilding_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemAltNames_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreet_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBaseShortening_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrBuilding_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrCity_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchem_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.RQObject_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrStreetShortening_, com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSettings_}

    annotations: []

Processor org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor matches [] and returns false.

Processor org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor matches [] and returns false.

Round 3:

    input files: {}

    last round: true

Compilation completed with 11 errors and 0 warnings

11 errors
0 warnings

/home/kelevra/java/KLADR/kladr/kladr-ejb/target/classes/com/kmware/ttk/kladr/model/KladrSchemStreet_.java
duplicate class: com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemStreet_

/home/kelevra/java/KLADR/kladr/kladr-ejb/target/classes/com/kmware/ttk/kladr/model/KladrSchemBuilding_.java
duplicate class: com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemBuilding_

/home/kelevra/java/KLADR/kladr/kladr-ejb/target/classes/com/kmware/ttk/kladr/model/KladrSchemAltNames_.java
duplicate class: com.kmware.ttk.kladr.model.KladrSchemAltNames_

...
```

and 8 more classes

Comment: Can you share a small sample to reproduce it? What JDK do you use as a target? Try to use Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK.

Comment: I am using Oracle jdk 1.6. I added some code in question

Comment: Check that you don't have multiple source roots with the same classes (or symlinks).

Comment: In sources roots I dont have same classes. The classes duplicates in directory 'target' wich is generating by maven while maven:compile

Comment: Did you import Maven project in IDEA? It should configure everything automatically. See also http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ.

Comment: Yep, I did it. Anyway I can solve this problem by simply excluding target folder from building in Project Structure. But I dont think that this is wright solution..

Comment: Normally `target/generated-sources` should not be excluded, there is something specific to your project that we don't know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18105/discussion-between-kirill-bazarov-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you somehow added the compile output of your module as a dependency? Either directly through IntelliJ or via Maven.

Comment: Yep I added it throw Project Structure

Comment: You should never edit project/module dependencies manually in a Maven imported project, all the dependencies are handled by Maven automatically and IDEA configured them on project import. All your manual changes will be discarded on the next reimport.

Comment: There is a **Reimport** button in the **Maven Projects** toolwindow.